# Substitution and Codomain

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have a system of equations

y = x^2

and

y = x + 2

We can use substitution to get the solution 
x = -1 or x = 2

But what if the codomain of the second function was all real numbers greater than or equal to 0.

How would we then use substitution in this case? If we just replace y in the first equation with x + 2, we still get the solution of -1 which is incorrect.

Comment: The codomain is talking about the restrictions in possible values of $y$.  It does not by itself restrict the possible values of $x$.  The fact that $-1$, an $x$-value, an element of the *domain* being less than $0$ is irrelevant to the point that the *codomain* not including any negative numbers.

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed that. What if the codomain of the second equation is all real numbers greater than or equal to 4? How would we solve in this case?

Comment: Well, in that case, then that implies that your domain could not have been all real numbers as that is a contradiction otherwise.  Now... it is not clear what you want to do with that information... whether you want to wait until some higher authority comes and tells you "Oh, you should use $[2,\infty)$ or $[5,42]$ as your domain" or something else like that, or if you want to try to find the largest possible subset of $\Bbb R$ that could work as a domain for your function without contradicting your choice of codomain.

Comment: It is often ignored... but to be unambiguous and rigorous, when defining a function you should also explicitly state what the domain of the function is and what the codomain of the function is as well.  At the moment, your function is ambiguously defined since it does not include information about the domain.  Once you define your domain, you will see if it is a contradiction.  Otherwise you will either be able to see whether any of the proposed solutions lie within it or not quite easily since you already found the solutions in the case the domain and codomain were all real numbers.

Comment: Why would it be contradictory to have a domain of all real numbers? Is it because values in that domain produce values that don’t belong to the codomain?

Comment: Precisely.  The function would fail to be well defined.

Comment: What about the equation y^2 = x? If we take x to the the independent variable, could we choose the codomain to be either all real numbers, or all real numbers greater than or equal to 0?

Comment: @Fransch. The relation defined as : the set of all pairs (x,y) such that y²=x is not a function. You may look at the graph the graph, and use  the vertical line test. The reason is that the equation is equivalent to : y = sqrt(x) or y = -sqrt(x). In orther word, this relation associates each x both with sqrt(x) and to - sqrt (x). No negative x witl belong to the domain ( for sqrt(x) does not exist in the system of real numbers). But  restricting the domain does not change anything to the fact that this relation is not a function.

Comment: @Fransch. You are right.  If you define a retation from A (  = real numbers > or = to 0 ) to B ( = real numbers> or = to 0) as the set ot all pairs (x,y) such that  y ² = x , yes, in that case , this    relation     is also a function.  To each x belonging to A, the relationn associates a unique y that is equal to +sqrt(x).    To say it informally :    the " - sqrt(x) " that bothered us previously does not exist anymore in this relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$x=-1 \implies y=x+2=1>0$$ so the codomain of non-negative values does not cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you want to think of equations in terms of functions.

So **let's say that each equation defines a function.**

y=x² defines the following function :

f = {(x,y) | y=x² }

( in words: f is the set - here, the function - that has , as elements, all the ordered pairs (x,y) satisfying the condition : y=x² )

The equation y = x+2 defines another function :

g = {(x,y) | y=x+2  }.

Now, what you want is to **solve the system**: to find all the x, y that satisfy both equations.

In terms of functions, it means you want to find all the pairs (x,y) that satisfy both the condition to belong to f and the condition to belong to g.

If ever you find a pair (x,y) that belongs both to f and to g, you need not worry about "domain" and " codomain".

Why?

Simply because :

- if (x, y) belongs to f then ***by definition***, x belonngs to the domain of f ( any first element of a pair that belongs to a function belongs to its domain, for by definition, the domain of a function is the set of all firsts elements of the pairs belonging to that function) ; and, by the same reasoning, if (x,y) belongs to f, then, by definition y belongs to the codomain.
- if (x,y) delongs to g, then , **by definition of " domain" and " codomain"** , x belongs to the domain of f and y belongs to the domain of g

Note : if ever the definitions of your functions contain special restrictions as to domain or dodomain, ***you will take this restrictions into account while solving your system of equations,*** , that is, *you xill exclude solutions that do not meet the criteria as to domain and codomain*, and therefore, you will never end up with solution pairs (x,y) that do not meet the conditions imposed on your functions.

Conclusion : if you understand that " x and y are solutions of the system of equations " **means exactly the same thing as** " the pair (x,y) belongs bothn to function f and to function g" , then you understand that **the uneasy case you were thinking about in your post is simply impossible!**

Why? Because : **"(x,y) belongs to both to f and to g " is equivalent to " x belo,gs both to domain of function f and to domain of function g , and y belongs both to domain of function f and of function g".**

In terms of graph the following sentences are equivalent :

- x and y are solutions of the system
- the point (x,y) is an intersection of the curve  representing f and of the curve representing g ( I suppose f and g are "simple" functions represneted by curves)
- x belongs to the domain of f and to and to the domain of g; y belongs to the codomain of g and to the codomain of g.

Note : Maybe the simplest way to show the case is impossible is to state the question like this : " could it not happen that I find a point (a,b) that is the intersection of the two curves representing f and g , but that, at the same time one of the two function is not defined at x= b or has no output b? " Answer: **it these cases, the point (a,b) would not be an intersection of the two graphs, for there would be no such common point!**

---

Solution of your particular problem.

We are looking for all values x, y that satisfy the system of equations, that is, we are looking for all pairs (x,y) that belong to both functions.

Since we want first that y = x+2, we must have : x = y-2

Since x= y-2 and y = x², we must have : y = (y-2)², and y²-5y+4 = O.

Solving for y gives : y = 4 OR y=1.

Applying " x = y-2  " gives : x = 2 OR x = -1

So, the only pairs that belong both to functions f and g are :

```
                   ( 2,4) and  (1, -1)
```

Fince f and g were defined on R, you see that each first element belongs to dom(f) and dom(g) and that each second element belongs both to codomain ( f) and codomain (g).